# How do I properly uninstall and reinstall SharePoint 2013? (Avoiding 503 Error)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, uninstallation, reinstall

I have looked in quite a few places but all the information I have seen does not address my scenario. Please note that I can probably just make a new server for my SharePoint 2013 installation but I think this might be one of those gems for people who do not have that luxury and facing the same problem.

SCENARIO:

I uninstalled a functional SharePoint 2013 setup by

1. uninstalling SharePoint 2013 on the SharePoint Server and
2. manually deleting the databases on the remote SQL Server.

When I tried to reinstall SharePoint 2013 though I kept getting a 503 Error on the Central Administration page which appears to be due to the Central Administration AppPool stopping.

SUGGESTIONS I HAVE TRIED:

1. Check the password of the account running the AppPool service.

   - I did that and the account have Domain Administrator privileges and is capable of logging into the SQL Server without issue using the same password.
2. Try uninstalling IIS.

   - I uninstalled and reinstalled IIS and it made still gave the 503 error.

I read on a blog post (let me know if I can send the link) that "[he] need[ed] to clean up the content db, virtual directory and app pool properly next time."

I believe I did this but I may be missing something and that bit of stuck information is probably what is causing the issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe you need to manually delete the SP admin site from IIS

Comment: Do you find any proper solution?